# React native : Tab bar button 'OnPress' not working outside the scope of the Tab bar

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-tabnavigator

[image]

As you can see, from the image attached:

1 arrow: The tab bar button does not work outside this scope

2 arrow: The tab bar button does work as it's inside the scope of the tab bar.

Code within navigation container:

```
 <BottomTab.Screen
    options={{
      //   tabBarIcon: ({}) => <VerifyFloatingButton />,
      tabBarOnPress: () => {
        null;
      },
      tabBarButton: ({}) => <VerifyButton size={30} />,
    }}
    name="asafaas"
    component={NullButton}
  />
```

Any way to make the button operational outside the scope of the tab bar?